# MVC Full Calendar doesn´t show the events

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I am implementing a calendar and I have encountered some difficulties because I am learning JavaScript alone and I have not mastered yet.

My problem is this: I can create the event and save it in the database, but the event and the color of it ... do not appear on the calendar ... can someone find out the solution or where is the problem?
If possible ... to create events ... being the color of this event always in random color?

**View**

```
<div id="calender"></div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><span id="eventTitle"></span></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button id="btnDelete" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Remover
                </button>
                <button id="btnEdit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right" style="margin-right:5px;">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Editar
                </button>
                <p id="pDetails"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="myModalSave" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Salvar Evento</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="col-md-12 form-horizontal">
                    <input type="hidden" id="hdID_Reserva" value="0" />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Cliente</label>
                        <input name="Nome" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Introduza o Nome" id="txtCliente">
                        <input type="hidden" id="txtID_Cliente" name="ID_Cliente" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Data de Entrada</label>
                        <div class="input-group date" id="dtp1">
                            <input type="text" id="txtDataEntrada" name="DataEntrada" class="form-control" />
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Data de Saida</label>
                        <div class="input-group date" id="dtp1">
                            <input type="text" id="txtDataSaida" name="DataSaida" class="form-control" />
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Número Quarto</label>

                        @Html.DropDownList("ID_Quarto", null, "Selecione o Quarto", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Número Pessoas</label>
                        <input id="txtNumeroPessoas" name="NumeroPessoas" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Número Noites</label>
                        <input id="txtNumeroNoites" name="NumeroNoites" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Preço</label>
                        <input id="txtPreço" name="Preço" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Observações</label>
                        <input id="txtObservaçoes" name="Observaçoes" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-success">Salvar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/AdminLTE/plugins/fullcalendar-3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/AdminLTE/plugins/fullcalendar-3.9.0/fullcalendar.print.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
@section Scripts{
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/AdminLTE/plugins/fullcalendar-3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var events = [];
            var selectedEvent = null;
            FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();
            function FetchEventAndRenderCalendar() {
                events = [];
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/CalendárioReservas/GetEvents",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                            events.push({
                                eventID: v.ID_Reserva,
                                clienteID: v.ID_Cliente,
                                quartoID: v.ID_Quarto,
                                inicio: moment(v.DataEntrada),
                                fim: v.DataSaida != null ? moment(v.DataSaida) : null,
                                noites: v.NumeroNoites,
                                pessoas: v.NumeroPessoas,
                                preço: v.Preço,
                                obs: v.Observaçoes
                            });
                        })

                        GenerateCalender(events);
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        alert('failed');
                    }
                })
            }

            function GenerateCalender(events) {
                $('#calender').fullCalendar('destroy');
                $('#calender').fullCalendar({
                    contentHeight: 400,
                    defaultDate: new Date(),
                    timeFormat: 'h(:mm)a',
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay,agenda'
                    },
                    eventLimit: true,
                    eventColor: '#378006',
                    events: events,
                    eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                        selectedEvent = calEvent;
                        $('#myModal #eventTitle').text(calEvent.clienteID);
                        var $quartoID = $('<div/>');
                        $quartoID.append($('<p/>').html('<b>DataEntrada:</b>' + calEvent.inicio.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm a")));
                        if (calEvent.fim != null) {
                            $quartoID.append($('<p/>').html('<b>DataSaida:</b>' + calEvent.fim.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm a")));
                        }
                        $quartoID.append($('<p/>').html('<b>ID_Quarto:</b>' + calEvent.quartoID));
                        $('#myModal #pDetails').empty().html($quartoID);

                        $('#myModal').modal();
                    },
                    selectable: true,
                    select: function (inicio, fim) {
                        selectedEvent = {
                            eventID: 0,
                            clienteID: '',
                            quartoID: '',
                            inicio: inicio,
                            fim: fim,
                            pessoas: '',
                            noites: '',
                            preço: '',
                            obs: ''
                        };
                        openAddEditForm();
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
                    },
                    editable: true,
                    eventDrop: function (event) {
                        var data = {
                            ID_Reserva: event.eventID,
                            ID_Cliente: event.clienteID,
                            DataEntrada: event.inicio.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A'),
                            DataSaida: event.fim != null ? event.fim.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A') : null,
                            ID_Quarto: event.quartoID,
                            NumeroNoites: event.noites,
                            NumeroPessoas: event.pessoas,
                            Preço: event.preço,
                            Observaçoes: event.obs
                        };
                        SaveEvent(data);
                    }
                })
            }

            $('#btnEdit').click(function () {
                //Open modal dialog for edit event
                openAddEditForm();
            })
            $('#btnDelete').click(function () {
                if (selectedEvent != null && confirm('Are you sure?')) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '/CalendárioReservas/DeleteEvent',
                        data: { 'eventID': selectedEvent.eventID },
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data.status) {
                                //Refresh the calender
                                FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();
                                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                            }
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert('Failed');
                        }
                    })
                }
            })

            $('#dtp1,#dtp2').datetimepicker({
                format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A'
            });

            //$('#chkDiaTodo').change(function () {
            //    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            //        $('#divDataFim').hide();
            //    }
            //    else {
            //        $('#divDataFim').show();
            //    }
            //});

            function openAddEditForm() {
                if (selectedEvent != null) {
                    $('#hdID_Reserva').val(selectedEvent.eventID);
                    $('#txtID_Cliente').val(selectedEvent.clienteID);
                    $('#txtDataEntrada').val(selectedEvent.inicio.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A'));
                    //$('#chkDiaTodo').prop("checked", selectedEvent.allDay || false);
                    //$('#chkDiaTodo').change();
                    $('#txtDataSaida').val(selectedEvent.fim != null ? selectedEvent.fim.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A') : '');
                    $('#ID_Quarto').val(selectedEvent.quartoID);
                    $('#txtNumeroNoites').val(selectedEvent.noites);
                    $('#txtNumeroPessoas').val(selectedEvent.pessoas);
                    $('#txtPreço').val(selectedEvent.preço);
                    $('#txtObservaçoes').val(selectedEvent.obs);
                }
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                $('#myModalSave').modal();
            }

            $('#btnSave').click(function () {
                //Validation/
                if ($('#txtID_Cliente').val().trim() == "") {
                    alert('Introduza um Título');
                    return;
                }
                if ($('#txtDataEntrada').val().trim() == "") {
                    alert('Introduza uma Data de Início');
                    return;
                }
                //if ($('#chkDiaTodo').is(':checked') == false && $('#txtDataFim').val().trim() == "") {
                //    alert('Introduza uma Data de Fim');
                //    return;
                //}
                else {
                    var startDate = moment($('#txtDataEntrada').val(), "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A").toDate();
                    var endDate = moment($('#txtDataSaida').val(), "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A").toDate();
                    if (startDate > endDate) {
                        alert('Data de Fim Inválida');
                        return;
                    }
                }

                var data = {
                    ID_Reserva: $('#hdID_Reserva').val(),
                    ID_Cliente: $('#txtID_Cliente').val().trim(),
                    DataEntrada: $('#txtDataEntrada').val().trim(),
                    DataSaida: $('#txtDataSaida').val().trim(),
                    ID_Quarto: $('#ID_Quarto').val(),
                    NumeroPessoas: $('#txtNumeroPessoas').val(),
                    NumeroNoites: $('#txtNumeroNoites').val(),
                    Preço: $('#txtPreço').val(),
                    Observaçoes: $('#txtObservaçoes').val()
                }
                SaveEvent(data);
                // call function for submit data to the server
            })

            function SaveEvent(data) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/CalendárioReservas/SaveEvent',
                    data: data,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.status) {
                            //Refresh the calender
                            FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();
                            $('#myModalSave').modal('hide');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('Failed');
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    </script>
```

**controller**

```
namespace WebApplication.Controllers
{

    public class CalendárioReservasController : Controller
    {
        private HotelEntities db = new HotelEntities();
        // GET: CalendárioReservas
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.ID_Quarto = new SelectList(db.Quarto, "ID_Quarto", "ID_Quarto");
            return View();
        }

        public JsonResult GetEvents()
        {
            try
            {
                var events = db.Reserva.Select(p => new
                {
                    ID_Reserva = p.ID_Reserva,
                    ID_Cliente = p.ID_Cliente,
                    ID_Quarto = p.ID_Quarto,
                    DataEntrada = p.DataEntrada,
                    DataSaida = p.DataSaida,
                    NumeroNoites = p.NumeroNoites,
                    NumeroPessoas = p.NumeroPessoas,
                    Preço = p.Preço,
                    Observaçoes = p.Observaçoes

                }).ToList();

                return Json(events, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                return Json(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult SaveEvent(Reserva e)
        {
            var status = false;
            using (HotelEntities dc = new HotelEntities())
            {
                if (e.ID_Reserva > 0)
                {
                    //Update the event
                    var v = dc.Reserva.Where(a => a.ID_Reserva == e.ID_Reserva).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (v != null)
                    {
                        v.ID_Cliente = e.ID_Cliente;
                        v.DataEntrada = e.DataEntrada;
                        v.DataSaida = e.DataSaida;
                        v.ID_Quarto = e.ID_Quarto;
                        v.NumeroPessoas = e.NumeroPessoas;
                        v.NumeroNoites = e.NumeroNoites;
                        v.Preço = e.Preço;
                        v.Observaçoes = e.Observaçoes;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    dc.Reserva.Add(e);
                }

                dc.SaveChanges();
                status = true;

            }
            return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } };
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult DeleteEvent(int eventID)
        {
            var status = false;
            using (HotelEntities dc = new HotelEntities())
            {
                var v = dc.Reserva.Where(a => a.ID_Reserva == eventID).FirstOrDefault();
                if (v != null)
                {
                    dc.Reserva.Remove(v);
                    dc.SaveChanges();
                    status = true;
                }
            }
            return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } };
        }
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public partial class Reserva
    {
        public int ID_Reserva { get; set; }
        public int ID_Cliente { get; set; }
        public int ID_Quarto { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DataEntrada { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DataSaida { get; set; }
        public int NumeroPessoas { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> NumeroNoites { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Preço { get; set; }
        public string Observaçoes { get; set; }

        public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
        public virtual Quarto Quarto { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: if, as you claim, the event is successfully saved to the database, but it does not show on the calendar, then you need to provide us a) sample data of an event which does not show up, and b) the server-side code which gets events from the database and sends them to fullCalendar. Also a couple of questions: Do you have any other events which _do_ show successfully in the calendar? If so, how did you create them? What is their data? Is there a noticeable difference between the data of working and non-working events?

Comment: P.S. Why do you destroy and re-create your calendar every time you fetch events from the server? This is expensive, unnecessary and bad practice. Instead, create the calendar once, and provide your event data via a custom callback as documented here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function. Then if you want to force an update from the server, you need only call the "refetchEvents" method of fullCalendar, instead of starting again from the beginning. And also the calendar will call for the next set of events from the server automatically whenever the user changes the date.

Comment: I'll follow your advice and test, then say something. Thank you !

Comment: I could not solve the problem and I continue without the sense where my error is.

Comment: well in order for me to help, you'll need to provide the missing code and sample data, and also answer all the questions I asked, all of which I mentioned in my first comment. Thanks

Comment: I added the controller ... it is doing everything right but the event is not visually marked on the map, but it saves it in the database. I think the problem should not be in events.

Comment: Actually, sorry...I just noticed something.... `$.each(data, function (i, v) {
 events.push({
 eventID: v.ID_Reserva,
 clienteID: v.ID_Cliente,
 quartoID: v.ID_Quarto,
 inicio: moment(v.DataEntrada),
 fim: v.DataSaida != null ? moment(v.DataSaida) : null,` ...etc . You know that fullCalendar doesn't speak Portuguese, right? The event properties have to be like the ones here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object otherwise it will ignore them. It doesn't know that `inicio` means `start`. I think it's likely your events don't show because fullCalendar doesn't recognise the properties

Comment: Apologies, I could have noticed this earlier...but so could you when you were writing it - did you not think that maybe your object had to match the documentation?

Comment: I have done debugging in json method and in fact all the data in the table is the one.
Exact, I want to select all the data and return them in fullcalendar

Comment: Sorry, I retract that comment. See my new comments. Your event objects do not conform to the fullCalendar documentation.

Comment: The problem was even at the start and end, problem solved and thank you!

Comment: I have written it as an answer, I would appreciate if you would mark it as "accepted" (you can click on the tick to make it turn green), thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event objects do not conform to the specification laid out at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object .

Here is the problem:

```
$.each(data, function (i, v) {
  events.push({
    eventID: v.ID_Reserva,
    clienteID: v.ID_Cliente,
    quartoID: v.ID_Quarto,
    inicio: moment(v.DataEntrada),
    fim: v.DataSaida != null ? moment(v.DataSaida) : null,
    noites: v.NumeroNoites,
    pessoas: v.NumeroPessoas,
    preço: v.Preço,
    obs: v.Observaçoes
  });
});
```

FullCalendar doesn't speak Portuguese. The event property names have to match the ones in the documentation otherwise it will ignore them. It doesn't magically know that `inicio` means `start`, for example. This means it cannot read any start time from your event, and therefore it doesn't know how to display it on the calendar.

Again as per the documentation, your events are also required to have a `title`, which you didn't appear to include at all.

Try this instead:

```
$.each(data, function (i, v) {
  events.push({
    id: v.ID_Reserva,
    clienteID: v.ID_Cliente,
    quartoID: v.ID_Quarto,
    title: '[You need to choose something to put here]',
    start: moment(v.DataEntrada),
    end: v.DataSaida != null ? moment(v.DataSaida) : null,
    noites: v.NumeroNoites,
    pessoas: v.NumeroPessoas,
    preço: v.Preço,
    obs: v.Observaçoes
  });
});
```

I have just changed the properties which matter for displaying the event. For other custom properties, you can call them anything you like, but the ones which have a defined purpose in fullCalendar must be named correctly.

P.S. You may need to change the code in your `eventDrop` function in a similar way.