# mvc Full Calendar Delete Events

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am implementing a calendar, but in the part of removing the calendar event, it has given me an error and I have not been able to remove this same event.

**JavaScript code**

```
$('#btnDelete').click(function () {
                if (selectedEvent != null && confirm('Are you sure?')) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '/CalendárioReservas/DeleteEvent',
                        data: { 'eventID': selectedEvent.eventID },
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data.status) {
                                //Refresh the calender
                                FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();
                                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                            }
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert('Failed');
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
```

**Method**

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult DeleteEvent(int eventID)
        {
            var status = false;
            using (HotelEntities dc = new HotelEntities())
            {
                var v = dc.Reserva.Where(a => a.ID_Reserva == eventID).FirstOrDefault();
                if (v != null)
                {
                    dc.Reserva.Remove(v);
                    dc.SaveChanges();
                    status = true;
                }
            }
            return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } };
        }
```

Comment: obvious question...what's the error, and where?

Comment: The error is in the javascript function that is in the topic and basically ... it does not run the method and just sends me the alert .... this error: function () {
                             alert ('Failed');
                         }

Comment: That doesn't tell me anything except that the ajax call went wrong somehow, but it's not specific enough. You need to check your browser's developer tools (Console and Network areas) for the real underlying error. If you don't know how to debug ajax requests, now would be a good time to research that.

Comment: gives me this error POST http: // localhost: 18459 / Calendar% A1rioReservas / DeleteEvent 500 (Internal Server Error).... jquery2.1.4

Comment: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'eventID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult DeleteEvent(Int32)' in 'WebApplication.Controllers.CalendárioReservasController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Nome do parâmetro: parameters

Comment: that suggests you aren't sending a value for `eventID` to the server. Just the line before your ajax request, do `console.log(selectedEvent.eventID);` and tell me if this variable actually contains a value or not. You can of course also look at the ajax request in your browser's Network tools and see what data was sent. You may need to send the value on the querystring instead of in the body, since it's a primitive type. The MVC model binder may not see it otherwise.

Comment: Also, if you changed your code as per my answer to the last question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50329556/mvc-full-calendar-doesn%C2%B4t-show-the-events), such that you have `events.push({
    id: v.ID_Reserva` in your code, then your events no longer have an `eventID` property, they have `id` instead. So that could be the cause. Happy debugging.

Comment: Eu coloquei desta forma console.log (selectedEvent.eventID); $ .ajax ({type: "POST"  ............. and I got the same error

Comment: ok that's right. And what result did you get? I don't expect it to solve the error, I expect it to output something (or perhaps an empty space!) which tell us whether that variable is populated or not, and thus whether you're sending anything to the server or not for the eventID parameter. Logging to the console is a debugging tool, it cannot fix bugs directly.

Comment: Thank you!!! I discovered the error through your help, it works !!!

Comment: the error was here  ----> data: { 'eventID': selectedEvent.id },instead of id I had eventID

Comment: No problem. Remember to pay attention to what properties your objects actually have available!